# convert a string into a character array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I have converted a String input into a character array by using toCharArray.
Now I want to do the same thing without using toCharArray.
How can I do it?

```
import java.util.*;
public class cArray{

public static void main(String[]args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Give A String");
    String s1 = input.nextLine();
    char[]data = s1.toCharArray();
  }

}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that...??? if you so interested in re-inventing the wheel....write a new language too!! :D

Comment: @NoobEditor There is nothing wrong with wanting to know what goes on under the hood. How will developers learn core skills otherwise?

Comment: @JamesB : agreed....there is nothing wrong in that but what OP asked was easy enough to google too and he would have learnt a lot about some other stuffs too while googling....asking on SO simply shows no effort was done finding it first as the same is easily available online....!!

Comment: Most IDEs come with the java library source code. Just debug through `toCharArray` and see how it's coded. And check the JLS to see the degree of standardisation to that an implementation must conform. You also learn to use a debugger and to follow a software spec: the most important skills of all.

Comment: @NoobEditor Ah but that isn't how you replied. You didn't say show some effort did you?

Comment: @JamesB : i expected a basic minimum understanding...bad from my side!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by building a new char array

```
   String s1="test";
   char[] carr=new char[s1.length()];
   for (int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
       carr[i]=s1.charAt(i);
   }
```

Don't tell us that , I don't want to use `charAt` also ;)

Comment: +1 because this is the correct answer and also the correct humor.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do like

```
public char[] toCharArray(String str) {
    char result[] = new char[str.length()];
    System.arraycopy(str, 0, result, 0, str.length);
    return result;
}
```

PS : This is what Java does inside `toCharArray()` method.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a little method yourself

```
public char[] toCharacterArray( String s ) {

   char[] array = new char[s.length()];
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      array[i] = s.charAt(i);
   }

   return array;
}
```

Now you decide which one you use toCharArray method or chartAt() as mentioned above with your own looping.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to use Character[] instead of char[] in this case?

Comment: no return type of method defined but you still able to return `null` and an `array`...2 different types...just curious!!